# Relative clauses with two verbs

Tags: relative-clauses

Which one is correct?

> A. Those viewers who do not understand this language well and they
> want to learn the lesson should see the subtitles.
>
> B. Those viewers who do not understand this language well and want to
> learn the lesson should see the subtitles.

Do we need the pronoun 'they' after 'and'? I think we don't. Am I right? Which one is the grammatical?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, B is correct.

You noun is : "Those viewers who do not understand this language well and want to learn the lesson"
No need for the extra pronoun as, where you put it in A, you are still in the noun part of the sentence.

Alternately, you could use:

"Those viewers who do not understand this language well and who want to learn the lesson"

which reinforced that you are talking about people with both these attributes. Like in "The flowers that are dead and wilted" vs "the flowers that are dead and that are wilted".

Comment: Yes, this is it. The subject (certain viewers) doesn't *need* to be "re-referenced" for the second clause after ***and*** - but if it *is* explicitly included, this should be done using (pronoun) ***who*** rather than ***they***.